# Javascript only working for one item in the list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby, timer

I have a script that counts from now till `due_date`. I made a .each to list `reservations`. each `reservation` has a `due_date`. The counter i made only works for the first row.. and seems to not work for the remaining rows.

- also i noticed when i added a new record, the new record added/ replaced with the other. because my timer changes dramatically when I added/ removed the record.

[image]

Here is the code that follows:

```html
    <% @reservations.where( "completed = ?", false).where( "due_date >= ?", DateTime.now).each do |reservation| %>
    
      <div id="dueDate-counter">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>days</td>
            <td>hrs</td>
            <td>mns</td>
            <td>secs</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td id="days"></td>
            <td id="hours"></td>
            <td id="minutes"></td>
            <td id="seconds"></td>
          </tr>
    
        </table>
    
        <script type="text/javascript">
          function countdown() {
            var now = new Date( <% DateTime.now %> );
            // var year = <%= reservation.due_date.strftime("%Y")%>;
            // var month = <%= reservation.due_date.strftime("%m") %>;
            // var day = <%= reservation.due_date.strftime("%d") %>;
            // var time = <%= reservation.due_date.strftime("%r") %>;
    
    
    
            // var eventDate = new Date(year, month, day, time);
            var eventDate = new Date("<%= reservation.due_date.localtime.strftime(" % m / % d / % Y % l: % M % P ") %>"); 

<%= puts "this is the reservation format below!!!!!!!" %>

<%= puts "#{reservation.due_date.localtime.strftime(" % m / % d / % Y % l: % M % P ")}" %>
              console.log(now);
            var currentTime = now.getTime();
            var eventTime = eventDate.getTime();
            console.log(currentTime);
            var remTime = eventTime - currentTime;
    
            var s = Math.floor(remTime / 1000);
            var m = Math.floor(s / 60);
            var h = Math.floor(m / 60);
            var d = Math.floor(h / 24);
    
            h %= 24;
            m %= 60;
            s %= 60;
    
            h = (h < 10) ? "0" + h : h;
            m = (m < 10) ? "0" + m : m;
            s = (s < 10) ? "0" + s : s;
    
    
    
            document.getElementById("days").textContent = d;
            document.getElementById("days").innerText = d;
    
    
            document.getElementById("hours").textContent = h;
    
            document.getElementById("minutes").textContent = m;
    
            document.getElementById("seconds").textContent = s;
    
    
            setTimeout(countdown, 1000);
          };
    
          countdown();
        </script>
    
      </div>
      
      
      <% end %>
```

Comment: _Identifiers in HTML must be unique._ `getElementById()` will always get the first element, thus the code works for first row.

Comment: so what would i use instead of getElementById?

Comment: You need to rethink approach, Are you using jQuery?

Comment: i think the countdown part is jQuery? im not too sure.. the timer i tried to make before i couldnt get to work so i went with this method. there is no way to get the script to attach to each list item individually?

Comment: You can use a class identifier instead of Id selector

Answer (score 0):

Instead of  `id` use `class`

```
document.getElementsByClassName("example");
```

Answer (score 0):

*Identifiers in HTML must be unique.* `getElementById()` will always get the first element, thus the code works for first row.

You can use specific CSS class then [Class Selector](https://api.jquery.com/class-selector/) can be used to target the elements. [`$.fn.find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) can be used to target the `TD` element in the parent element context.

In the snippet below arbitrary data is associated with element using `data-*` custom attributes, which can be fetched using [`$.fn.data()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/)

```js
function countdown(elem) {
    var now = new Date(elem.data('now'));
    var eventDate = new Date(elem.data('date'));
    var currentTime = now.getTime();
    var eventTime = eventDate.getTime();
    console.log(currentTime);
    var remTime = eventTime - currentTime;
    var s = Math.floor(remTime / 1000);
    var m = Math.floor(s / 60);
    var h = Math.floor(m / 60);
    var d = Math.floor(h / 24);
    h %= 24;
    m %= 60;
    s %= 60;
    h = (h < 10) ? "0" + h : h;
    m = (m < 10) ? "0" + m : m;
    s = (s < 10) ? "0" + s : s;

    elem.find(".days").text(d); 
    elem.find(".hours").text(h);
    elem.find(".minutes").text(m);
    elem.find(".seconds").text(s);
    setTimeout(function(){
        countdown(elem);
    }, 1000);
};

$('.dueDate-counter').each(function(){
    countdown($(this))
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<% @reservations.where( "completed = ?", false).where( "due_date >= ?", DateTime.now).each do |reservation| %>
  <div class="dueDate-counter" data-now='<% DateTime.now %>' data-date='<%= reservation.due_date.localtime.strftime(" % m / % d / % Y % l: % M % P ") %>'>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>days</td>
        <td>hrs</td>
        <td>mns</td>
        <td>secs</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="days"></td>
        <td class="hours"></td>
        <td class="minutes"></td>
        <td class="seconds"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <% end %>
```

Comment: I get the NaN error for the values. I made my code the way it is for this reason because firefox doesnt support.

Comment: @MichaelLombardo, check `elem.data('now')` and `elem.data('date')`

Comment: okay so the `elem.data('now')` comes up in console as undefined. the `elem.data('date')` shows the proper date.

Comment: @MichaelLombardo, You can test with `var now = new Date();` or update `date-now='<% DateTime.now %>'`

Comment: I got this to work in a way however im not getting a count down it just gives me the timer amount from then i refresh the page. just stays frozen. the `date-now` needs to be changed to `data-now`.... that was the error.  but i need help making the countdown work

Comment: @MichaelLombardo, can you share the generated HTML in fiddle?